# SQL questions - Medium difficulty

Tags: sql

I am working through this link and I am stuck on Q7 and Q8 on this website: http://sqlzoo.net/a3m.htm

My attempt for Q7 is:

```
SELECT tprod.dscr, sum(qnty), max(tpurcd.recv)
FROM tprod, tpurcd
WHERE tprod.code = tpurcd.prod
GROUP BY tprod.dscr, tpurcd.recv
```

Q8 attempt:

```
SELECT tpurcd.cust, tpurcd.recv, qnty
FROM tpurcd, tprod
WHERE tprod.code = tpurcd.prod
AND tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric
```

Table info is listed here: http://sqlzoo.net/a3.htm

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

.7. For each product show the description and the total number ordered and the date of the most recent order.

*(you shouldn't group by tpurcd.recv)*

```
SELECT tprod.dscr, sum(qnty), max(tpurcd.recv)
FROM tprod
INNER JOIN tpurcd ON tprod.code = tpurcd.prod
GROUP BY tprod.dscr
```

.8. Show the customer code, the received date and the total value of all purchase orders with a total value of at least £475.

*(the expression `tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric` was hanging)*

```
SELECT tpurcd.cust, tpurcd.recv, sum(tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric)
FROM tpurcd
INNER JOIN tprod ON tprod.code = tpurcd.prod
GROUP BY tpurcd.cust, tpurcd.recv
HAVING sum(tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric) >= 475
```

Comment: Hey cyberkiwi, thanks for the quick reply...are u sure about your answer for Q8?

Comment: You should verify that yourself, you have to do something for the exercise right? But you are right, it was wrong, so updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql

## 7

```
SELECT tprod.dscr as Description, sum(tpurcd.qnty) as Quantity, max(tpurcd.recv) as 'Most Recent Order'
FROM tprod
INNER JOIN tpurcd ON tprod.code = tpurcd.prod
GROUP BY tprod.dscr
```

## 8

```
SELECT tpurcd.cust as 'Customer Code', tpurcd.recv as 'Received Date', sum(tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric) as 'Total Value'
FROM tprod
INNER JOIN tpurcd ON tprod.code = tpurcd.prod 
group by tpurcd.cust, tpurcd.recv
having sum(tpurcd.qnty * tprod.pric) > 475
```